# Cannot access Azure Jenkins dashboard

Tags: azure, jenkins, dashboard

I created a Jenkins server on Azure according to this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/jenkins/install-jenkins-solution-template. 
The problem is that when I try to access the Jenkins dashboard by entering the dns of this form: http://jenkins2517454.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com, I get 404 not found nginx. I double checked the dns.
Any idea what could have gone wrong?

Comment: Could you check port 8080 has opened.

Comment: I also did the test and got the same error as you, so I think the document miss some steps and need to repaired.

Comment: @Charles-MSFT I have followed the same document. Its working fine.

Comment: Is that real? I just follow the document and get error, what other actions you does?

Comment: Probably the ssh key.

Comment: @Charles-MSFT Could you please follow the steps mentioned below.

Comment: For me it was an ssh - generation issue. The public key should have been on the local machine, not on the azure vm. I will also post my answer and if it solves @Charles-MSFT problem as well, I will mark as solved. Kudos to the thorough reply, we really appreciate it. I will upvote it even if I cannot try it as I am using Ubuntu and as far as I know, Putty is for Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating Jenkins on Azure, set up tunnel using Putty in order to access Jenkins via http://localhost:8080/.

**Step1:** Open Putty and enter the Hostname and Port.

[image]

**Step2:** Configure the tunnel [Source port: 8080 & Destination 127.0.0.1:8080] and click add.

[image]

**Step3:** Click on **Open** to login using jenkinsadmin and password

[image]

**Step4:** After you have started the tunnel, navigate to http://localhost:8080/ on your local machine.

Get the initial password by running the following command in the command line while connected through SSH to the Jenkins VM.

sudo cat /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword

[image]

**Step6:** Select Install suggested plugins on the next page and then create a Jenkins admin user used to access the Jenkins dashboard.

**Welcome to Jenkins!**

[image]

Comment: CHEEATLA Thanks for your answer. I create Jenkins with a password. So If the same steps?

Comment: Yes, using putty create tunnel and click open, then you can enter your username and password.